# Make maven ignore / continue after "Unable to parse command line options"

Tags: java, maven, command-line-interface, gitlab-ci

While reworking a CI pipeline script, i stumbled into

```bash
$ mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean compile
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --no-transfer-progress
```

when trying to add `--no-transfer-progress` to the default setup. This happens in a shell executor runner, of course due to an outdated Maven version. Although i have already found a workaround via SDKMAN! to get recent maven versions onto such runners, i would like my CI script to be as generalized as possible, i.e. not failing for project pipelines that are missing an `.sdkmanrc` file and simply want to rely on the default maven version on that runner (which i don't have control over).

So, is there a way to make maven ignore unrecognized options and continue execution nevertheless?

Comment: simple answer to that. No there is no way. Just use most recent version onf your CI ... instead of relying on the `.sdkmanrc` ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I don't have control over the runner configuration, which is a shell executor type (so simply using an image with a recent maven version also is not an option).

Comment: If this is a shell executor, couldn't you simply check the return value of the Maven command and run a different one if the first one fails?

Comment: You CI uses and old Maven version which the error message indicated `.....--no-transfer-progress`...

Comment: @khmarbaise as i stated in my post i'm perfectly aware of that. `-ntp` was introduced in Maven 3.6.1 as per the [release notes](https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.6.1/release-notes.html). My post asks how to have maven simply ignore unknown command line options (just as it does for user properties) so a generic set of preferred options can be used w/o knowing the maven version they will be run against beforehand.

Comment: @JFabianMeier That's a helpful idea. However, instead of failing and "degressively" removing options by chance i decided for a more deterministic approach that *progressively* enhances the CLI options string, which i've now documented in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77197309/1246547).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As all the feedback so far indicated that this is not possible, i integrated a bash script into the CI pipeline that progressively enhances the CLI options depending on the currently available maven version:

```bash
INSTALLED_MAVEN=$(mvn -version | grep -o "Apache Maven [\.0-9]*" | cut -d" " -f 3)

# --no-transfer-progress was introduced in Version 3.6.1
if [ $(printf "${INSTALLED_MAVEN}\n3.6.1" | sort -V | head -1) = "3.6.1" ]; then
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS="$MAVEN_CLI_OPTS --no-transfer-progress"
fi

# --color was introduced in version 3.8.2
if [ $(printf "${INSTALLED_MAVEN}\n3.8.2" | sort -V | head -1) = "3.8.2" ]; then
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS="$MAVEN_CLI_OPTS --color=always"
fi
```

Clearly has room for improvement i.e. by making the version comparison algorithm [DRY](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7EmboKQH8lM&t=5825s), but so far this works like a charm for us.

Nevertheless always keen to learn if there's a smarter way to achieve this.